# Should I frame my problem as VRP or as Transportation Problem

Tags: optimization, constraint-programming, operations-research, vehicle-routing

Please help me whether I should model the below problem as VRP or as Transportation problem.

The problem I am trying to solve is:

- I have multiple products to transport from multiple Warehouses to 2 shops.
- I have a fleet size with varying capacity of vehicles available at each warehouse
- I know the supply and demand requirements for each product at each of the node.

Constraints are:

- One vehicle will go from warehouse to one shop (It should not take multiple warehouse in one route)
- Preference to the supply from one source satisfying the entire demand of one shop rather than aggregating supply from individual sources.

Could you help me understand what category of problem this is?

If I model it as a transportation problem, how do I factor in the capacity of vehicle? I have not come across transportation problems that take into account the capacity of vehicle being used to transport.

Comment: I think it is neither a VRP or a Transportation Problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate further on how I can model this? Any code/literature will be helpful

Comment: I would start modeling this as a MIP.